# AgGrid: Restoring state is moving auto group column to the right

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am seeing something weird with ag-grid v25.1

So, when you add rowGrouping for the first time, It is showing at the left.
see below:

[image]

Then just save the state (with grouping added).
Now restore the state. See below Row Grouped column is moved to right.

[image]

Grid Declaration

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [sideBar]="sideBar"
  [rowGroupPanelShow]="rowGroupPanelShow"
  [pivotPanelShow]="pivotPanelShow"
  [debug]="true"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/column-state/#save-and-apply-state

Any workaround on this or anything on how to fix it?

Plnkr for repro https://plnkr.co/edit/ja0JupIYgY8g7Pwy?preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4405#issuecomment-807081835) of AgGrid. The auto group column is moved to the far right after calling `ColumnApi.applyColumnState()`. A simple workaround in the meantime is:

- Save the current column state somewhere using `ColumnApi.getColumnState()`.
- Apply the new column state.
- Check if auto group column exist. The default column ID is `'ag-Grid-AutoColumn'`.
- If so, move it back to where it originally was by calling `ColumnApi.moveColumnByIndex()` using the last column state info.

```js
saveState() {
  window.colState = this.gridColumnApi.getColumnState();
  window.group = this.gridApi;
}

getAutoGroupColIndex(colState) {
  return colState.findIndex(
    (column) => column.colId === 'ag-Grid-AutoColumn'
  );
}

restoreState() {
  if (!window.colState) {
    console.log('no columns state to restore by, you must save state first');
    return;
  }

  const oldAutoColumnIndex = this.getAutoGroupColIndex(window.colState);

  this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: window.colState,
    applyOrder: true,
  });

  const newAutoColumnIndex = this.getAutoGroupColIndex(
    this.gridColumnApi.getColumnState()
  );

  this.gridColumnApi.moveColumnByIndex(
    newAutoColumnIndex,
    oldAutoColumnIndex
  );
}
```

#### Demo

https://plnkr.co/edit/MS2w9vxMTpcDbOTp

Comment: According to that confirmed bug link above, this will be fixed in their 23 April release in version 25.2.0. https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/